# Convert axis x-value to figure value

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I convert an axis' x coordinate value into the figure's x coordinate value?

I want to align some text with the axis left side, but I want to draw it in a static position on the figure.

Answer (score 0):

So there are different ways to do what you want, I think this link provides two methods: one is placing text based on point coordinates and the second is placing text based relatively to an axis

https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/16030/coordinate-systems-and-text

Comment: Thanks, this is close but I want to split which transform is used for the x and y coordinates.